# How to map objects with similar names in different documents to the same ElasticSearch / Kibana field?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, mapping, nested-attributes, kibana

Consider the following JSON files :-

File 1 -

```
{
   "titleSony": "The Matrix",
   "cast": [
      {
         "firstName": "Keanu",
         "lastName": "Reeves"
      }
   ]
}
```

File 2 -

```
{
   "titlePixar": "The Matrix",
   "cast": [
      {
         "firstName": "Laurence",
         "lastName": "Fishburne"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now, since 'titleSony' & 'titlePixar' essentially refer to the same object, is there any way to map it to the same field in ElasticSearch?

Similary, also diplay it as the same field in Kibana?

Answer (score 0):

ElasticSearch doesn't support relationships between documents. They do, however, have a guide on [managing relational data](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html). Implementing an application-side join might look something like this:

File 1 (_type=movie)

```
{
   "titleSony": 123,
   "cast": [...],
}
```

File 2 (_type=movie)

```
{
   "titlePixar": 123,
   "cast": [...],
}
```

File 3 (_type=movieTitle)

```
{
   "titleID": 123,
   "title": "The Matrix",
}
```

There are [no plans](https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/2499) to support application-side joins in Kibana.